# GetJson with Object.values with commas within text. How to get rid of these commas?

Tags: arrays, getjson

I would like to get a specific value from a JSON with GetJson but it is inserting commas within the value/text. Here is the structure of my JSON:

```
{"api":
{"results":10,"fixtures":
        [{"fixture_id":293298,
        "league_id":1251,
        "league":
            {"name":"CONMEBOL Libertadores",
            "country":"World",
            "logo":.....
```

I am trying to get the "name" value i.e. "CONMEBOL Libertadores" instead I'm getting "C,O,N,M,E,B,O,L, ,L,i,b,e,r,t,a,d,o,r,e,s".

```
  $(document).ready(function(){


$.getJSON("proxliberta.json", function(data) {

  $.each(data.api.fixtures, function() {

  });

  console.log(Object.values(data.api.fixtures[1].league.name));

  document.getElementById('val').innerHTML = Object.values(data.api.fixtures[1].league.name)

});
```

});

How can I eliminate these commas within my response? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
Object.values(data.api.fixtures[1].league.name)
```

try changing to,

```
data.api.fixtures[1].league.name
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Comment: that worked really well. Thanks so much for the fast reply!

Comment: @MarceloFla That's alright, can you please mark the answer as correct and upvote if it helped. Cheers.